# Using SQLFORM.grid & request.args

Tags: python, database, web2py

At the moment I am displaying selected data in a database with a HTML table.

default.py:

```
def show():
post = db.games(request.args(0))
reviewRows = db(db.reviews.game_id == request.args(0)).select()
return locals()
```

show.html

```
{{extend 'layout.html'}}

<h2>{{=post.title}}</h2>

<i>Desc: {{=post.description}}</i>

<h2>Reviews:</h2>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>Review title</th>
        <th>Review</th>
    </tr>
    {{for row in reviewRows:}}
    <tr>
        <td>{{=row.title}}</td>
        <td>{{=row.review}}</td>
    </tr>
    {{pass}}
</table>
```

But I would like to use a SQL.grid so that I can sort & search the table.

I have tried

```
reviewRows = SQLFORM.grid(db.reviews.game_id == request.args(0)).select()
```

But this just links me back to the index page. I'm assuming its because its not taking the argument correctly?

default.py:

```
def index():
    gridHome = SQLFORM.grid(db.games, editable=False, create=False, csv=False, deletable=False, details=False, links = [lambda row: A('View Post',_href=URL("default","show",args=[row.id])), lambda row: A('Review',_href=URL("default","review",args=[row.id]))])
    return locals()
```

Comment: You're mentioning something about linking you back to the index page and have tagged this with web2py.  Can you share your routing function? Apologies -- I haven't used web2py, but I don't see where this would perform redirects.

Comment: I have added all of my code to the question.

It's not meant to link me back to the index page, the idea is that when I click on 'View Product' a page loads containing an SQL.grid displaying reviews related to the selected product. At the moment I'm using a simple html table which works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SQLFORM.grid` uses the URL args to construct its own URLs, so if the base URL of the grid action already uses one or more URL args, you must specify this via the `args` argument:

```
reviewRows = SQLFORM.grid(db.reviews.game_id == request.args(0), args=request.args[:1])
```

The above tells the grid that all internal URLs it constructs should include `request.args[:1]` as a URL arg before adding any of its own URL args.

Also, note that you should not add a `.select()` to `SQLFORM.grid` as you have in your example code.